# Disable back button in a specific Screen (React Navigation Stack)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

## Hello!


I need to disable the back button on the navigation bar. help me plsss.

**Routes**

- Home: I don't want to leave the application
- Success: I don't want to go back to Checkout.

[Example: click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFOHe.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { OrderProvider } from '../contexts/order';

import Home from '../pages/Home';
import Checkout from '../pages/Checkout';
import Success from '../pages/Checkout/success';

const AppStack = createStackNavigator();

const AppRoutes = () => (
  <OrderProvider>
    <AppStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}> 
      <AppStack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />  <-- here
      <AppStack.Screen name="Checkout" component={Checkout} />
      <AppStack.Screen name="Success" component={Success} /> <--- here
    </AppStack.Navigator>
  </OrderProvider>
);

export default AppRoutes;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { View} from 'react-native';

const Success = () => {
  return (
    <View />
  );
};

export default Success;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
const Home = () => {
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const onBackPress = () => {
        return true;
      };

      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);

      return () =>
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
    }, []),
  );
  // ...
};
```

```
const Success = ({navigation}) => {
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const onBackPress = () => {
        navigation.navigate('Home');
        return true;
      };

      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);

      return () =>
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
    }, []),
  );
  // ...
};
```

---

I've set it up so that clicking back on the `Home` screen does nothing by returning `true` when the `hardwareBackPress` event is called.

For the `Success` screen I navigate back to `Home`.

I assumed this is the behavior you're looking for from reading your question.

---

It is important that you don't forget to import `useFocusEffect` from
react-navigation everywhere you use it:

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

---

When to return `true` or `false` in the `hardwareBackPress` event handler function is explained in the react navigation documentation:

> Returning true from onBackPress denotes that we have handled the
> event, and react-navigation's listener will not get called, thus not
> popping the screen. Returning false will cause the event to bubble up
> and react-navigation's listener will pop the screen.

If you want to read more read the documentation here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-android-back-button-handling/.